# tkinter combobox unfolder with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using combobox in tkinter and I want to use keyboard shortcuts to drop down lists instead of using mouse by clicking. Is there any methods to implement this?

I tried and found if the focus is on combobox, I could use "Down" to unfolder. How could I change "Down" to other shortcuts?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, it's harder for us to help you if we don't know what you've already tried.